# New fields for Contact (GenderIdentity and Pronouns) not returned by SOAP API v57

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap, developer-console, describesobject

The reference page [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) and the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_fields_gender_inclusive.htm&release=242&type=5) indicates that there are two new fields on the `Contact` object called `GenderIdentity` and `Pronouns` that should be available with v57 of the API. But using the SOAP API, if I make a call to `describeSObjects` for the `Contact` object at `<url>/services/Soap/u/57.0`:

```
<se:Envelope xmlns:se="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <se:Header xmlns:sfns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <sfns:SessionHeader>
            <sessionId>XXX</sessionId>
        </sfns:SessionHeader>
        <sfns:CallOptions>
            <client>XXX</client>
        </sfns:CallOptions>
    </se:Header>
    <se:Body>
        <describeSObjects xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns1="sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <sObjectType>Contact</sObjectType>
        </describeSObjects>
    </se:Body>
</se:Envelope>
```

those fields are not returned. If I try to [describe the schema using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeSObject.htm) by [executing it in the Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&type=5), I still don't see those fields returned. Why is that? We use the SOAP API for one of our products and we cannot access these fields that our customers see in Salesforce elsewhere. I don't see any other documentation indicating why this could be / how to fix it.

Comment: But, you see the fields in the UI/object manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite being logged in as a System Administrator and seeing the fields under Object Manager, I had to go to my profile settings > Object Settings > Contact and enable access to the two fields. I realized this based on [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_gender_setup.htm&type=5).

Comment: where do you find my profile settings > Object Settings

Comment: @2095377 under Setup > Users > Profiles > <my profile> > Object Settings